# Categories changed incorrect after redraw

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

Categories do not change despite I changed config.

https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-j7hoi

I want to show categories like in config.

Comment: Are you telling about first time it won't do anything and 2nd click it is changing ?

Comment: if initial state is column, works correct. if default state is linear, categories redraw incorrect!

Comment: Following the [documentation](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#optimal-way-to-update) you need to use a function to update the data.

Comment: unfortunately this example works same incorrect for my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In API we can read:

> type: Highcharts.AxisTypeValue
>
> (...) In a category axis, the point names of the chart's series are used for
>   categories, if not a categories array is defined.

So, you also need to update the `x` values:

```
} else {
  this.setState({
    options: {
      ...,
      series: [
        {
          data: [[0, 3], [1, 45], [2, 12]]
        }
      ]
    }
  });
}
```

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-4x8np

**API:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type